# How do I connect to microsoft sql server remotely with raspberry pi 4

Tags: sql-server, raspberry-pi, freetds

```
I am trying to connect to microsoft sql server remotely with Raspberry pi 4 but I am getting error as below. What is the reason?
```

I proceeded as stated in the link but failed. [text](https://tryolabs.com/blog/2012/06/25/connecting-sql-server-database-python-under-ubuntu)

```
import pyodbc

dsn='sqlserverdatasource '
user='....'
password='...'
database='msbd'


con_string='DSN=%s';UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;'% (dsn, user, password, database)
print("debug1")

cnxn=pyodbc.connect(con_string)
print("debug2")
```

**Error:
[08S01] [08S01][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (20009) (SQLDriverConnect)**

I proceeded as stated in the link but failed. [text](https://tryolabs.com/blog/2012/06/25/connecting-sql-server-database-python-under-ubuntu)

**Error:
[08S01] [08S01][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (20009) (SQLDriverConnect)**

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server (MS SQL) <> MySQL !!! Taglist will be adjusted.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74221873/edit) your question to include the data source definition. Does the data source name include a trailing space: `dsn='sqlserverdatasource '`?